# Redux reducer hasMap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have hashMap in my redux store, I want change isChecked value for children id: `'A2'`, on desktop and android everything work fine but on iphone I have problem, if I check children with id `'A2'` dont know why this children is going to the last position.

Init list:

```
- NameOne
- NameTwo
- NameThree
```

After click on checbox with id A2

```
- NameOne
- NameThree
- NameTwo
```

My hashMap

```
const childrens = {
  'A1': { name: "NameOne", isChecked: false },
  'A2': { name: "NameTwo", isChecked: false },
  'A3': { name: "NameThree", isChecked: false },
};
```

My reducer:

```
case "SELECT_CHILDREN": 
  const id = 'A2';
  return {
    ...state,
    [id]: {
      ...state[id],
      isChecked: !state[id].isChecked
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Keys order in JavaScript objects is not specified. And order depends on JS engine. So basically you can't rely on it and it is not a bug.

If you need a concrete order for entities you can use arrays.
And shape of your store will be something like that:

```
{
  order: ['A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
  items: {
    'A1': { name: "NameOne", isChecked: false },
    'A2': { name: "NameTwo", isChecked: false },
    'A3': { name: "NameThree", isChecked: false },
  }
};
```